# after doing a git difftool --dir-diff, files are modified for some reason

Tags: git, newline, difftool

After doing `git difftool --dir-diff`, my workspace files are modified for some reason. I've been guessing that it's converting the line endings between `crlf` and `lf` etc... However, doing `"git config core.autocrlf false`" or "`git config --global core.autocrlf false`" don't make any difference. I have tried using both windiff and beyond compare as the custom diff tool but it doesn't help. This is bad since every time I view some changes in my .csproj file, the project is reloaded since it said the file has been modified externally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only other way an automatic conversion can be declared is through [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) (see [`gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)):

- with directives like `*.txt eol=lf` ("[Git: Default all text files to unix line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10734395/6309)") or `* text=auto` ("[Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9976986/6309)")
- with content filter (smudge script)

Comment: Other than that, check if the issue persists when you are making a diff on *another* clone of your repo. Or on a clone of your repo on *another* workstation.

Comment: I didn't see any .gitattributes file anywhere so I created one in the directory of my project and added `* -text` to disable LF normalization but it didn't work. By the way, I'm using Git Shell that's included from GitHub for Windows instead of Git. This behavior is the same for all the other clones, it still seems to be editing the files somehow. I have again made sure to turn off all `core.autocrlf` settings with both `--system` and `--global` flags. Any ideas? @VonC

Comment: Want to make another note that if all my changes are added to staging area then it seems to no longer modify my files.