# Is it possible to commit a file that defies the line ending behavior specified by .gitattributes?

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes

If a `.gitattributes` file is added to given directory, with exactly the following content:

```
*.txt    text
```

Is there any possible way that a **new file** or a **previously normalized file** (e.g. all LF line-endings) could be committed to that directory and not be normalized?  I.e., is there any possible way that **new CRLF line endings** could be introduced into the repository after enabling `.gitattributes` with `text` mode specified?

To paraphrase again, is this `.gitattributes` file an *absolutely foolproof* way to prevent new CRLF lines from being committed to `*.txt` files in the directory that contains the `.gitattributes` file? I want to convince my colleagues that the `.gitattributes` file is entirely sufficient, and that further measures to exclude CRLFs (e.g. a server-side hook) are unnecessary.

An answer should either confirm that it is impossible to override the line-ending behavior specified by `.gitattributes`, or provide a counterexample explaining how one could circumvent the `.gitattributes` file and sneak in some CRLF line endings.

Comment: Note to self: here is another case of trying not circumvent gitattributes eol rules: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17123998/6309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily through [`gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), since **negative pattern** are forbidden.

There is actually a patch being proposed this days (March 2013) to [Make `!pattern` in `.gitattributes` non-fatal](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-Make-pattern-in-gitattributes-non-fatal-td7578826.html).

So you need to put a global rule like `*.txt` only in `.gitattributes` files present in sub-directories where you *known* you won't need CRLF.

And reserve more fine-grained `text` rules in `.gitattributes` present in directories with mixed content.

---

[kostmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105137/kostmo) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161535/is-it-possible-to-commit-a-file-that-defies-the-line-ending-behavior-specified-b/17162483#comment31201008_17162483) the [EGit bug 421364](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421364):

> Until this is implemented, I recommend this setup:
>
> 1. For each Eclipse project, go to `Properties > Resource` and change "`New text file line delimiter`" to `Other: Unix`. Commit the resulting `.settings/org.eclipse.core.runtime.prefs` files.
> 2. Don't configure any `.gitattributes` or "`core.autocrlf`" for Git.
>      This means that files will have the same line endings in the working directory as in the repository. Git and EGit will not convert any file contents.
>
> With 1., all new files that are created in Eclipse will have correct (`LF`) line endings, even when created by a user on Windows.
>
> For files that are already in your repository with `CRLF`, you can fix them and commit the result. I recommend using `dos2unix` or `fromdos` on the command line.

Note: that issue ([bug 421364](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421364)) has just now (March 25th, 2014) been requalified as duplicate of [bug 342372](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372) by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/people/larsvogel.html).

So, the support of `.gitattributes` by JGit is "assigned", but its implementation is <del>still in progress</del>.

The implementation is being reviewed (January 2015):

- "[review 1614](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/1614/)" **Add basic support for `.gitattributes`**

> Core classes to parse and process `.gitattributes` files including support for reading attributes in WorkingTreeIterator and the dirCacheIterator.

- "[review 35377](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/35377/)" **Adds the git attributes computation on the treewalk**

> Adds the `getAttributes` feature to the tree walk.
>   The computation of attributes needs to be done by the `TreeWalk` since it needs both a `WorkingTreeIterator` and a `DirCacheIterator`.

---

Update August 2018: the bug mentioned above ([bug 342372](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372)) depends on [JGit bug 537410](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537410), which just got resolved.
"**JGit rebase and stash dont preserve line ending**s"

> The problem is that the `ResolveMerger` during `processEntry()` does not remember the `CheckoutMetadata` (in which JGit stores filters and eol-attributes) for the files and then checks them out in `checkout()` ignoring any attributes or filters.
>
> `ResolveMerger.cleanUp()` has the same problem.

[JGit commit 4027c5c](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=4027c5c9ffc9fb99b2c06b9a7ecdeb18838e8218) (from [review 127290](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/127290/)) should fix that.
THanks to **Thomas Wolf** an [active contributor to JGit](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg03414.html).

That gives hope for EGit:

> EGit in general leaves all this eol handling in staging/merging/checkout to JGit.
>   The only places where EGit has to care about it is in the compare framework when it has to read index entries itself, and there it already properly handles `CheckoutMetadata`.

Comment: OK, so to paraphrase my question, is the above `.gitattributes` file an *absolutely foolproof* way to prevent new CRLF lines from being committed to `*.txt` files in the directory that contains the `.gitattributes` file?

I want to convince my colleagues that the `.gitattributes` file is sufficient, and that further measures to exclude CRLFs (e.g. a server-side hook) are unnecessary.

Comment: @kostmo yes, as long as you keep config `core.autocrlf` to `false` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016763/6309): you can define `eol` rules in the `.gitattributes`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12702862/6309

Comment: Are you saying that if `core.autocrlf` was `true`, a user could produce a commit that defies the `.gitattributes` setting?

Comment: Nope: gitattributes rules have precendence over a global config like core.autocrlf: see http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes: "The `core.eol` configuration variable controls which line endings Git will use for normalized files in your working directory; the default is to use the native line ending for your platform, or `CRLF` if `core.autocrlf` is set. ... If the `text` attribute is unspecified, Git uses the `core.autocrlf` configuration variable to determine if the file should be converted."

Comment: Somehow some CRLF's got into our repository some time after setting the offending files to be "text" format in the `.gitattributes` file and normalizing the line endings of all of those files. My suspicion is that JGit/EGit (Eclipse's built-in Git client) is not respecting the same rules that the native Git command-line client uses. Since the enforcement is only client-side, it seems that it is possible to circumvent `.gitattributes` normalization after all.

Comment: [Here is the EGit bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421364) directed toward `.gitattributes` line ending support.

Comment: @kostmo interesting, thank you. I have included that reference in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> To paraphrase again, is this .gitattributes file an *absolutely foolproof way*

No. Git has a lot of conveniences to make the usual tasks easy and put speedbumps in the way of questionable things, but it won't limit your control over your own repo.

> I want to convince my colleagues that the .gitattributes file is entirely sufficient, and that further measures to exclude CRLFs (e.g. a server-side hook) are unnecessary.

They are necessary.  Nobody can control what others do in their own repos.

```
git update-index --cacheinfo \
        100644,`git hash-object -w --no-filters path/to/file`,path/to/file
```

From the [git hash-object docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-hash-object.html)

> **--no-filters**
>   Hash the contents as is, ignoring any input filter that would have been chosen by     the attributes mechanism, including the end-of-line conversion. If the file is read from standard input then this is always implied, unless the --path option is given.