# Git global settings and dealing with line endings once and for all

Tags: git, github

What exactly should I write in the terminal to global config my git to save all files always with line endings = LF. I work on Windows but most of my co-workers use macOS and I want to save all my work on my PC with line endings = LF setting

I found this tutorial [Dealing with line endings - GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#example), but I still don't know what command should I put in the terminal to configure git to save all cloned projects on my drive with that setting.

Can you please help me?

I tried:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.autocrlf true text eol=lf
```

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your editor uses CRLF:

`git config --global core.autocrlf true`

If your editor uses LF:

`git config --global core.autocrlf input`

You can also use a **.gitattributes** file in each project to save certain types with certain line endings. I use something like this because git will try to convert the crlf byte sequence in say images if you use `* eol=lf`

```
*.php eol=lf
*.scss eol=lf
*.sass eol=lf
*.css eol=lf
*.js eol=lf
*.json eol=lf
*.sql eol=lf
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `* text=auto eol=lf` does not try to convert the CRLF byte sequence in non-text files, as of Git 2.10. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40977008/1009155
In other words: It leaves line endings unchanged on checkout, but converts CRLF to LF on text files only when committing. So it is a good option given that most Windows apps can now handle LF line endings.

Comment: In other words, `* text=auto eol=lf` in **.gitattributes** is equivalent to `core.autocrlf input` in git config. Similarly, `* text=auto` in **.gitattributes** is equivalent to `core.autocrlf true`.